# AirPlay button a la phone app on WatchKit?

Tags: watchkit

The phone app in watchOS shows an AirPlay icon which when clicked switches the audio input and output to the watch itself, using it as it were a bluetooth headset, I guess.

I'd like to do the same for a calling app I work on, but couldn't find anything in the WatchKit documentation.

Is this not available as a public API? AFAIS there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for MPVolumeView on watchOS: http://www.openradar.me/20783803

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering this myself too, and after the (relatively) large amount of Googling I've done trying to figure this out, I'm assuming that it doesn't exist, unfortunately.